# Template localization in symfony2

Tags: symfony, localization, twig

Some languages like Persian(Farsi) has Right-to-Left structure.

To do i18n and l10n completely, I should translate strings and flip layout.

I translate strings using Translation component completely.

Now I'm trying to flip layout. How can I load `rtl` version of CSS based on `loacle` in twig file within symfony project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put another way, you want to load the right CSS file according to your locale.

Twig allows you to handle this smoothly.
Here's an example on how you can do it,

First, create a global **`app/Resources/views/base.twig.html`** template which contain

```
{% block head %}
{% block direction %}
    <HTML>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
{% endblock %}
    <head>
    <!-- put here your head meta data -->
{% endblock %}
```

You can then add an English and Persian (or whatever language you want) version of your base template

**app/Resources/views/base.en.html.twig**

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
```

In the Persian version of your base template and since you need RTL for html, and specialized CSS, you need to set more details on it,

**app/Resources/views/base.fa.html.twig** (I guess "fa" is the language code for Persian)

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block direction %}
    <HTML DIR="RTL">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheet %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <!-- Add here your specified stylesheets -->
{% endblock %}
```

Then, using a three level inherentence you can inherit from the right base template according to your locale. Here's what should your layout contain first,

```
{% extends '::base.' ~ app.request.locale ~ '.html.twig' %}
```

Comment: I accept your answer, but I was looking for a way in assetic. may be a plugin over assetic